# Компиляторы с поддержкой C++11

Tags: c++

Какие компиляторы поддерживают C++11?

Comment: ну да, gcc поддерживает C++0x  во многом, здесь подробнее написано http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Полностью стандарт С++11 пока ни один компилятор не поддерживает. Наиболее полная поддержка у gcc 4.7.

Answer (score 7):

- Компилятор `C++` в `Visual Studio 2010 / 11 Beta` тоже обладает частичной поддержкой `C++11`. *Подробнее можете посмотреть [**здесь.**](https://web.archive.org/web/20160127043203/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx)*
- Информация о поддержке `C++11` в менее распространенных компиляторах представлена [**тут.**](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport)

Answer (score 5):

К началу 2016 года, все основные компиляторы (Clang, GCC, VC++) поддерживают С++11.
Наиболее полная и актуальная таблица фич/компиляторов находится на [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support).

Visual Studio 2015 [поддерживает все фичи С++11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) за исключением ["N2634, SFINAE problem for expressions"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2634.html).

G++ полностью поддерживает С++11 начиная [с версии 4.8.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).
Поддержку С++11 в libstdc++ (реализация стандартной библиотеки) можно [посмотреть здесь](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x).

Clang полностью поддерживает С++11 начиная [с версии 3.3](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html).

Answer (score 4):

gcc 4.7.0 поддерживает, но пока только в качестве эксперимента.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2013. Как говорят сами специалисты из microsoft, там реализовано уже более 80% стандарта. Работы продолжаются